# Laravel: Get base URL

Tags: php, laravel, base-url

Simple question, but the answer seems quite hard to come by. In Codeigniter, I could load the URL helper and then simply do

```
echo base_url();
```

to get my site's URL. Is there an equivalent in Laravel?

Answer (score 360, accepted):

You can use the URL facade which lets you do calls to the [URL generator](http://laravel.com/api/4.1/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.html)

So you can do:

```
URL::to('/');
```

You can also use the application container:

```
$app->make('url')->to('/');
$app['url']->to('/');
App::make('url')->to('/');
```

Or inject the UrlGenerator:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Your\Class\Namespace;

use Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator;

class Classname
{
    protected $url;

    public function __construct(UrlGenerator $url)
    {
        $this->url = $url;
    }

    public function methodName()
    {
        $this->url->to('/');
    }
}
```

Comment: And despite its possible appearance from the example, this is relative to the Laravel's root path, so if you're installed in `/something/` it'll make the right URL.

Comment: @deFreitas and #ceejayoz how to use URL::to with laravel localization?

Comment: @MubasharIqbal If I understood your question, `{{URL::to('/my-page.html')}}` at view and `echo URL::to('/my-page.html');` at the code

Comment: nice handler, in my case:  `<a class="button is-primary" href="<?= URL::to('/'); ?>/atencion/reporte" target="_blank">`, thanks!

Comment: May also need to add `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;`

Answer (score 219):

Laravel < 5.2

```
echo url();
```

Laravel >= 5.2

```
echo url('/');
```

Comment: Could you expand this answer to include an explanation instead of just a code-snippet?

Comment: Exam: I have site in local: http://localhost/abc
In Codeigniter: echo base_url(); => I get http://localhost/abc
In Laravel: echo url(); => I get http://localhost/abc too.

Comment: Use this for an url with segmentation: url().'/'.\Request::segment(1).'/'.\Request::segment(2)

Comment: Note that this no longer works in 5.2: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/11479 You can use `url('/')` instead however

Comment: `asset('/')` seems better to me because it has trailing slash which is necessary in base href.

Comment: I tried url(/some/route) in routes/web.php and it is still not working on deployed server

Answer (score 62):

For Laravel 5 I normally use:

```
<a href="{{ url('/path/uri') }}">Link Text</a>
```

I'm of the understanding that using the `url()` function is calling the same `Facade` as `URL::to()`

Comment: Note: if your website is served over https you can use the `secure_url()` function the same way, and this will produce an https link. Using `url()` on an https site will still produce an http link.

Comment: This one worked for me. Also useful to know the secure_url() syntax as well. Thanks.

Comment: I'm using Lumen 5.4. There `url()` generates a http or https link based on the protocol of the request. On the other hand `secure_url()` doesn't exist. Did this change in Laravel 5.4 too?

Comment: No, it's part of Larvel 5.4. I can't really comment because I have never used Lumen but the 5.4 Laravel documentation for `secure_url()` is available here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-secure-url

Answer (score 55):

Updates from 2018 Laravel release(5.7) documentation with some more url() functions and it's usage.

> Question: To get the site's URL in Laravel?
>
> This is kind of a general question, so we can split it.

**1. Accessing The Base URL**

```
// Get the base URL.
echo url('');

// Get the app URL from configuration which we set in .env file.
echo config('app.url');
```

**2. Accessing The Current URL**

```
// Get the current URL without the query string.
echo url()->current();

// Get the current URL including the query string.
echo url()->full();

// Get the full URL for the previous request.
echo url()->previous();
```

**3. URLs For Named Routes**

```
// http://example.com/home
echo route('home');
```

**4. URLs To Assets(Public)**

```
// Get the URL to the assets, mostly the base url itself.
echo asset('');
```

**5. File URLs**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

$url = Storage::url('file.jpg'); // stored in /storage/app/public
echo url($url);
```

**Each of these methods may also be accessed via the URL facade:**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

echo URL::to(''); // Base URL
echo URL::current(); // Current URL
```

**How to  call these Helper functions from blade Template(Views) with usage.**

```
// http://example.com/login
{{ url('/login') }}

// http://example.com/css/app.css
{{ asset('css/app.css') }}

// http://example.com/login
{{ route('login') }}

// usage

<!-- Styles -->
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Login link -->
<a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a>

<!-- Login Post URL -->
<form method="POST" action="{{ url('/login') }}">
```

Comment: URL generates the values based on the request's `root` URL unless you use `forceRootUrl `. That means, if you write APIs and your consumers request from a different domain, the URLs will be built based on that host. Check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36471503/2190689

Answer (score 21):

To get it to work with non-pretty URLs I had to do:

```
asset('/');
```

Comment: To my need this is the best `<base href="{{ asset('/') }}" />`

Comment: Kudos to you! It fits just right in `<base href="..."/>` because of trailing slash

Answer (score 17):

This:

```
echo url('/');
```

And this:

```
echo asset('/');
```

both displayed the home url in my case :)

Answer (score 14):

Laravel provides bunch of helper functions and for your requirement you can simply

use **url()** function of Laravel Helpers

but in case of **Laravel 5.2** you will have to use **url('/')**

[here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-url) is the list of all other helper functions of Laravel

Comment: @sambellerose and is you want to access inner folders/files you can do `url('/css/style.css')`

Answer (score 10):

There are multiple ways:

- `request()->getSchemeAndHttpHost()`
- `url('/')`
- `asset('')`
- `config('app.url')`
- `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`

Answer (score 7):

To just get the app url, that you configured you can use :

```
Config::get('app.url')
```

Comment: This definition is only used in Laravel cli. `app.url` it appears to be a fallback

Comment: Well anymore, env('APP_URL') would probably be the best option.

Answer (score 7):

Check this -

```
<a href="{{url('/abc/xyz')}}">Go</a>
```

This is working for me and I hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility: `{{ URL::route('index') }}`

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted, as it actually works and no one gave the option as well?

Comment: Not my downvote but I'm guessing the reason is that you can't guarantee the naming of your root route to be "index" in every app.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use URL::to('/') to display image in Laravel. Please see below:

```
<img src="{{URL::to('/')}}/images/{{ $post->image }}" height="100" weight="100">
```

Assume that, your image is stored under "public/images".

Answer (score 3):

I used this and it worked for me in Laravel 5.3.18:

```
<?php echo URL::to('resources/assets/css/yourcssfile.css') ?>
```

IMPORTANT NOTE: This will only work when you have already removed "public" from your URL. To do this, you may check out [this helpful tutorial](http://icodehub.in/remove-public-from-url-laravel-5/).

Answer (score 3):

By the way, if your route has a name like:

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], 'specialWay/edit', 'SpecialwayController@edit')->name('admin.spway.edit');
```

You can use the `route()` function like this:

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('admin.spway.edit')}}" class="form form-horizontal" id="form-spway-edit">
```

Other useful functions:

```
$uri = $request->path();
$url = $request->url();
$url = $request->fullUrl();
asset()
app_path();
// ...
```

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php

Answer (score 3):

You can use facades or helper function as per following.

```
echo URL::to('/');
echo url();
```

> Laravel using Symfony Component for Request, Laravel internal logic as per
>   following.

```
namespace Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation;
/**
* {@inheritdoc}
*/
protected function prepareBaseUrl()
{
    $baseUrl = $this->server->get('SCRIPT_NAME');

    if (false === strpos($this->server->get('REQUEST_URI'), $baseUrl)) {
        // assume mod_rewrite
        return rtrim(dirname($baseUrl), '/\\');
    }

    return $baseUrl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I found an other way to just get the base url to to display the value of environment variable APP_URL

```
env('APP_URL')
```

which will display the base url like http://domains_your//yours_website. beware it assumes that you had set the environment variable in .env file (that is present in the root folder).

Answer (score 1):

you can get it from Request, at laravel 5

```
request()->getSchemeAndHttpHost();
```

Answer (score 0):

I also used the `base_path()` function and it worked for me.