# Laravel Jquery Ajax 404 error and migration URL Issue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5, response

I am facing an error while working with laravel & Ajax.

Here is my code.

```
 <button id="openBtn" class="btn blue pull-right"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Add Certification</button>

$(".editcertifictns #openBtn").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
  type:'get',
  dataType:'html',
  async:false,
  url:'getcertifications',
  success:function(response){
    $("select[name=certictnsoptn]").html(response);
    $(".modelPophldr,.modelPop").show();
    $("#catagry_name").val("").focus();
    $(".formitmpic").hide();
    $(".modelPop").animate({'margin-top':'25px'});
  },
});
```

Routes.

```
 Route::get('getcertifications',['uses'=>'GblgetapiController@getcertifications']);
```

Controller

```
public function getcertifications(){
    $arr = DB::table('master_cirtfctnassc')->get();
    $string ="";
    foreach ($arr as $arr) {
        $string .= "<option value='.$arr->cirtfctnassc_name.'>".$arr->cirtfctnassc_name."</option>"
    }
    return $string;
}
```

Binding area..

```
  <div class="modelBody">
      <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" name="certictnsoptn">
          <option></option>
        </select>
      </div> 
    </div>
```

When Clicking on the button, the app will sent an ajax..

I am attaching the  screenshot of firebug when ajax perform...

look the URL hovered...:(((((

[image]

How can I use the full url in js file without making a issue in migration stage....
Anybody please help me to solve this issue ???? :(:(:(:(:(:(:(

Comment: Do you have a `<script>` tag for the jQuery code?

Comment: its included a jquery file code dude...

Comment: Well the way you present it above then you have HTML in your js, dude! But for considering the question, why not using a relative URL? Or, use the base URL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23059918/laravel-get-base-url

Comment: i want the full url in js file... not in laravel controller or layout... when i use the url() methord, its getting error :((((

Comment: Generating HTML code inside controller `getcertifications()` is not cool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the Full URL available in all your Javascripts, you could set a global variable somewhere in your page like so (in blade):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var BASEURL = "{!! url('/') !!};";
</script>
```

So later you can do:

```
$.ajax({
  type:'get',
  dataType:'html',
  async:false,
  url: BASEURL + 'getcertifications'
});
```