# Get base url in blade laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to display metaimage when i share my link. But i am unable to get image. here is my code. please suggest me what is in my code. Iam new laravel.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="../storage/uploads/{{$page->meta_image}}">
```

Comment: meta_image is a property of the $page variable being sent to the view(blade template), can you add the code before the return view()  is called for us to see.. then we can help you,

Comment: Have you tried to use URL('/') method ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/34010117/6066343

Comment: You can add simply {{ url('/path_to_image) }}

Comment: @LaurineMF yeah its work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<meta property="og:image" content="{{ url('/path_to_image') }}">
```

Ref. : https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers

Comment: thank get solved by adding  this { url('/') }}  check below   <meta property="og:image" content="{{ url('/') }}/storage/uploads/{{$page->meta_image}}">

Comment: try this also looks more better `{{ url('/storage/uploads/$page->meta_image') }}`

Answer (score 3):

For you use storage path :

```
// (assuming you using storage location)
$path = storage_path();
$path = storage_path($page->meta_image);
<meta property="og:image" content="{{$path}}">
```

To Get the base Path:

```
$path = base_path();
```

To Get Public Path :

```
$path = public_path();

$path = public_path('css/app.css');
```

To Get Site URL Path :

```
$path = url("your_image_path"); // http://example.com/...
```

Reference : [Laravel Path Helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers)

Comment: Thank you i solved this by doing this   <meta property="og:image" content="{{ url('/') }}/storage/uploads/{{$page->meta_image}}">

Comment: Glad you got the solution to your problem. You can also use the base path like `content="{{ base_path() }}/storage/uploads/{{$page->meta_image}}"` or storage_path like `content="{{ storage_path() }}/uploads/{{$page->meta_image}}"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ENV('APP_URL', 'http://localhost')` from `.env` file